# changing background-image property on-the-fly

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, background-image

It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome: changing the css property 'background-image' via jQuery.

I'm trying to stylize themes for my website and I have made a few color options, but the background-image property doesn't seem to be changeable via the handler .css in Chrome

```
$('#h_background').css('background-image',"url('backgrounds/h_"+currentTheme+".png'");
```

however, it works fine in FF; any suggestions =)?

edit: loading new stylesheets that have the background-image property defined as something else works fine.  I do find it strange that explicitly declaring it does not seem to work =(

Comment: Does google chrome's console (CTRL+SHIFT+J) complain about anything?

Comment: Please create a **pared-down** working example showing your problem and put it online, preferably at some place like http://jsfiddle.net Not only will this help us find your problem, you may find your problem in the process of paring down your code.

Comment: You're missing a ) at the end of the url after .png'. It should be "url('backgrounds/h_"+currentTheme+".png')". Could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @devius: you rocked my world with that one.  fixes everything yay!

Comment: Still wondering if chrome complained about "unable to parse css declaration bla bla bla...". FireFox does so.

Comment: @Salman: maybe I'm looking at the wrong place, where should it be in the CTRL+SHFT+J view?

Comment: @Salman: Chrome did indeed complain about a missing parentheses, but only after I added more code it seems

Comment: Seems like Chrome does not complain about CSS errors like Firefox.
In Firefox open up error console (CTRL+SHIFT+J) and look at Warnings tab, you'll notice CSS parsing errors reported there. This probably is not the case in Chrome.
Nevertheless, devius is right about the missing `)` and Firefox does report CSS parsing failures inside CSS file, inline styles or even when you use jQuery to manipulate CSS (see http://jsfiddle.net/KkyUV/ in FireFox and look at error console).

Comment: @sova I know it's a bit late but should I add the correct answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a **)** at the end of the url after .png'. It should be

```
"url('backgrounds/h_"+currentTheme+".png')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your code in load event:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // your code for the image
});
```

Comment: it doesn't seem like it, but when typing in variable names that I know are declared in the script, chrome complains that they are undefined.  And Chrome changes regular images with the .attr() method, but background-image is not working for whatever reason